# How to mutate node-config in memory

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-modules, node-config

I'm trying to mutate the value of my config in memory for testing, I've tried adding `process.env.ALLOW_CONFIG_MUTATIONS=true` in several spots in the application, as well as through the command line and my `.env` file.

The `config.util.getEnv('ALLOW_CONFIG_MUTATION')` method always returns undefined.

I've also tried using `importFresh` and `MockRequest` as per examples I've seen online, neither of which allow me to mutate the config in memory, and then reset the value later.

Does anyone have any idea about this?

**Update**: here's an example of what I'm trying to accomplish

```
const config = require (config);
const app = new App(config)

it(`does a thing with base config`, () => {  ...  }

it('does a thing with modified config, () => {  
    // here i would need to modify my config value and
    // have it change the original config that's currently in 
    // application memory

    config = newConfig  

    expect(config.get('newValues')).to.equal(true)
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If it is the same config module that I have used (I think I is) then add a `custom-environment-variables.js` OR `test.js` with you test config.

test.js will need an `ENV=test` to work and the custom-environment-variables need something like (for Mac's and NPM) `$ npm run funcTest` -> `yarn serverRunning && NODE_ENV=test wdio wdio.conf.js`.

the JSON will look something like

```
{
  test: 'Value'
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response @MrPickles - I'm actually already using a test config, but I need to modify it's value mid test.

I'll update my question with an example!

Comment: OK. I can't think of a time when config would change mid process, or if this is even possible. I am guessing you have found a way and therefor want to test it. if so ... (pause to thing) ... it may need a new test (`npm run test-config`) to get the desired effect. But as I said I can't think of a way to get in that state and unfortunately can't help :( at this time. but will have a think on it none the less.